# Find the extreme points of the set $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3): |x_1| + |x_2| + |x_3| \le 1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I need to find the extreme points of the set $\mathcal{A} = \{(x_{1},x_{2}, x_{3}) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: |x_{1}|+|x_{2}|+|x_{3}|\leq 1\}$.

I have already found that $\mathcal{A}$ is convex, closed, and bounded.

The definition of an extreme point given in my text is the following:

> A point $x$ of a convex set $X$ is called an **extreme point** of $X$ if no other points $u\in X$ and $v\in X$ exist such that $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{2}u + \frac{1}{2}v$.

This definition doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to me, though. It's very awkwardly worded. I checked another book and found a definition I like better:

> A vector $x$ is said to be an **extreme point** of a convex set $C$ if $x$ belongs to $C$ and there do not exist vectors $y,z \in C$, and a scalar $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $$ y \neq x, \, z\neq x, \,\, x = \alpha y + (1-\alpha) z. $$

It goes on to say that an equivalent definition is that $x$ cannot be represented as a convex combination of some vectors of $C$, all of which are different from $x$.

However, neither of these books tell me how to go about finding extreme points. Indeed, I have searched the internet, and cannot find any examples of finding extreme points that are helpful.

Therefore, I was wondering if someone could please tell me how to go about doing it.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**: I realize this is an octahedron, and my intuition tells me that the extreme points are the vertices, but I don't know how to show this, nor do I know how to show that these are the ONLY extreme points. Please help.

Comment: Based on these definitions any point on the surface of $\mathcal{A}$ is an extreme point of $\mathcal{A}$. $x_1=x_2=x_3=1/3$ would be an example of such extreme point. Since the surface is smooth, points on it belong to a tangent plane (aka tangent space). For ex. at a given $x$ it is called $T_x\mathcal{A}$. So  any straight line on the tangent plane cannot cross $\mathcal{A}$. Perhaps a more interesting problem would be to find the diameter of this region, i.e. the largest distance between 2 points in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @minimax that might be a more interesting problem, but it is not the one I was assigned. Any point on the surface and not just the vertices would be extreme points? Then, how would I prove that these were the ONLY extreme points?

Comment: By the definition you provided, any point on the surface is an extreme point. I can't think of anything else, unless you add more restrictions, such as largest $x_3$.

Comment: Is this region $\mathcal{A}$ really smooth?

Comment: @minimax $(1/2, 1/2, 0)$ is on the surface, but it's not an extreme point because $(1/2, 1/2,0) = 1/2 (1,0,0) + 1/2(0, 1, 0)$

Comment: It's a sphere on the taxicab metric. So it has flat sides. You have to find the vertices. It is not smooth as initially thought. If you think in the simpler 2d problem it helps you figure out.

Comment: @minimax so...the vertices are the only extreme points?

Comment: Yes, because you could find two different points, $ y, z$ in the same edge  as $x$ to satisfy $x= \alpha y+(1-\alpha)z$, with $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: @minimax then how do I show that no interior point is an extreme point?

Comment: The surface of $\mathcal{A}$ is an octahedron and the extreme points are $(\pm1, 0, 0)$, $(0, \pm1,0)$ and $(0,0,\pm 1)$.

Comment: @minimax I don't have any results at my disposal that tell me that polyhedral sets have only their vertices as extreme points. Could you direct me to one?

Comment: if you have an interior point $x$ of $\mathcal{A}$, you could bracket it by $0$ and $a x$ where $a$ is slightly bigger than 1. Since the interior of $\mathcal{A}$ is an open set, for any given point in $\mathcal{A}$ you can always find a $\delta>0$ such that the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x$, $B_\delta(x)\subset\mathcal{A}$. Hence, no interior points could be an extreme of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: In this problem, you have 12 edges for the surface of $\mathcal{A}$. Just pick one of the edges for ex., in the first quadrant of the $x_1-x_2$ plane. That is $x_1+x_2=1$, then any point along this edge could written as $\alpha (1,0, 0)+(1-\alpha)(0, 1, 0)$. Hence, except for the two vertices of this edge, the other points are not extreme points according to the definition of extreme points.

Comment: @minimax thanks! You should have put all this together in an answer, though.

Comment: @minimax I have another question for you which isn't really related to this one: can a non convex set have extreme points?

Comment: yes. The extreme points would be on intersection of the non-convex set and the convex hull of the non-convex set.

Comment: @minimax what about the set $\mathcal{B} = \{ (x_{1}, x_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x_{2} \leq (x_{1})^{2} \}$? Its convex hull would be the whole plane, and then the intersection of it with its convex hull would be the set itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the procedure is to guess & verify.

In this case your intuition is correct, Since
${\cal A} = \operatorname{co} \{ \pm e_k\}_{k=1}^3 $ (unit vectors) you
need only check that these points are indeed extreme points since all
other points cannot be extreme points.

To see why no other point can be an extreme point, suppose
$x \in \operatorname{co} \{b_k\}_k$ (with the $b_k$ being distinct
and finite in number) and
$x \notin \{ b_k \}_k $. Then $x = \sum_k \lambda_k b_k$ where
$\lambda_k \ge 0$, $\sum_k \lambda_k = 1$. Since $x \notin \{ b_k \}_k $, there must be at least one $\lambda_i \in (0,1)$. Then
$x = \lambda_i b_i + (1 -\lambda_i) {1 \over \sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k }\sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k b_k$ and since
$b_i, {1 \over \sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k }\sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k b_k \in \operatorname{co} \{b_k\}_k$ we see that $x$ cannot be an extreme point. Hence the extreme points must be a subset of the $b_k$.

(**Aside**: The above proof is not quite correct as it is possible that
$b_i = {1 \over \sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k }\sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k b_k$. If this is the case, then we can write
$x = {1 \over \sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k }\sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k b_k$ and repeat the process as necessary until $b_i \neq {1 \over \sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k }\sum_{k \neq i} \lambda_k b_k$.)

To see why the $\pm e_k$ are extreme, we have the following useful
result:

Suppose $C$ is convex, $h$ some direction, and that $b \in C$ is the unique solution to the problem $\langle h, b \rangle = \sup_{c \in C} \langle h, c \rangle$. Then $b$ is an extreme point of $C$. (This is
straightforward to prove by contradiction.) Note that this is a
sufficient, not necessary requirement for $b$ to be extreme.

**Proof**: Suppose that $b \in C$ is the unique solution to the problem $\langle h, b \rangle = \sup_{c \in C} \langle h, c \rangle$
for some direction $h$, but that $b$ is not an extreme point. Then there are $y,z \in C$ distinct from $b$ and
$\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that $b= \alpha y + (1-\alpha)z$. Since
$\langle h, b \rangle = \sup_{c \in C} \langle h, c \rangle \ge \alpha \langle h, y \rangle + (1-\alpha) \langle h, z \rangle  = 
\langle h, b \rangle $, we see that 
$\langle h, y \rangle = \langle h, z \rangle= \langle h, b \rangle$,
which contradicts the fact that $b$ is the unique minimiser.

If we choose $h = e_1$ then we see that 
$\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle = 1 =\sup_{x \in {\cal A}} \langle e_1, x \rangle$, hence $e_1$ is extreme. The other points follow in a
similar manner.

Comment: how do I know that no other points cannot be extreme points?

Comment: what are the $\{ b_{k} \}_{k}$?

Comment: I am proving the result for the convex hull of an arbitrary finite collection of point $b_k$, not just the $\pm e_k$.

Comment: wouldn't a proof that a point is an extreme point of a polyhedral set if and only if it is a vertex also suffice? The problem is that I cannot find one that does not also include that the point is a basic feasible solution, and the proofs are very complicated because of that. How would I prove that if x is an extreme point then it must be a vertex? (The other direction isn't hard).

Comment: How do you define vertex?

Comment: let's use the definition: "A vector $x$ of a polyhedron $P$ is called a **vertex** if there exists $c$ such that $\langle c,x \rangle \leq \langle c, y \rangle $ ($\langle \cdot \rangle$ represents the inner product) for all $x \neq y \in P$".

Comment: @DaenerysDracarys: The last result I stated above shows that a vertex (using your definition) is an extreme point. In general, the converse is not true (that is, there is a convex set with an extreme point that is not a vertex). However, for a polyhedron I believe an extreme point is also a vertex.

Comment: I'm sure it will make a lot more sense to me in the morning. I'll take a  deeper dive into this then and hopefully, it all works out. If not, I'll ask more questions.

Comment: Good luck! Convex analysis has some tantalisingly obvious results whose proof require a lot of grind.

Comment: is there a way to express this octahedron as a matrix? I was reminded that for polyhedral sets: columns of the matrix of coefficients are linearly independent for the positive components.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by expressing it as a matrix.

Comment: If you take the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & -e_1 & -e_2 & -e_3   \end{bmatrix}$, then you have ${\cal A} = \{ A x | x \ge 0, \sum_k x_k = 1 \}$. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: maybe. I've got to think about it a little more. I'm working on a different problem right now: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475393/find-set-of-extreme-points-and-recession-cone-for-a-non-convex-set But I'll come back to this one soon.

Comment: do you mind adding to your answer the details of the proof for the result you mention at the end? I could do a bounty if you want.

Comment: I added a short proof.